# What are the advantages of using Azure App Service to deploy a docker application instead of Azure Container Instance?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-instances

What are the advantages of using Azure App Service to deploy a docker application instead of Azure Container Instance?
I found out that Azure Container instances don't have any networking-related capabilities in terms of restricting app access. Are there any more advantages of using Azure App Service to deploy a container?

Answer (score 1):

There are many advantages of using Azure app service over azure container instance

1. Azure app service is PAAS(platform as a service) on the other side azure container the instance is an IAAS(infrastructure as a service).
2. In azure app service directly integration of custom domain is available
3. Integration with the application gateway to handle the traffic load
4. It offers auto-scaling and high availability.
5. Automated deployments from GitHub, Azure DevOps, or any Git repo to support a continuous deployment model
6. Host background jobs(Web Jobs)